# How to call a hook inside a hook? (or alternative as this cant be done :D)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so I've created a custom hook that needs to be fired on page view

so I thought I could just call this hook inside `useEffect` but it doesn't look like this is possible

so does anyone know how I can do this?

it will be triggering Google Analytics once I fire it so it has to be onload. is this possible?

ok here's an example

```
export const usePageView = props => {
    const counter = useSelector(state => state) // useSelector coming from react redux
    console.log(counter, '===')
}

import { usePageView } from '../myhooks'

export const myComponent = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      usePageView() // get error saying Error: Invalid hook call.
},[])

}
```

Comment: Add a [mre] to the question, we can only debug what we can see.

Comment: @ChrisG does that help?  added some code

Comment: Your hook isn't returning anything. A hook basically works like this: `const counter = usePageView();` at the start of the functional component, then more code that does stuff based on `counter`. The idea is that if the value returned by the hook changes (because the hook's internal state changes), so does the component that uses that value because it's re-rendered.

Comment: If your actual goal is to implement `componentDidMount()` in a functional component, you don't need a hook in the first place. Here's a simple custom hook example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-field-pe7sn

Comment: @ChrisG probably just a regular function then?

Comment: Not sure, all I know is this is a classic [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Edit your question so it describes your actual goal. You can obviously mention what you've tried so far to solve it, but "calling a hook inside a hook" is definitely not the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: please see answer to Jered below. I said this: "I just want to trigger a page view onload. I have a GTM helper library so that will be called inside my hook. I don't want to directly call GTM inside myComponent as that is not scalable or reusable. so I want a hook to do this. I don't want to use HOCs as they are ugly. but maybe I don't need a hook. just a regular function? –"

Comment: oh and I need to use `useSelector` inside my hook to get the app state

Comment: Ok, so to break it down: your React app has multiple pages, and each time the user views a page, you want to fire some function, once. Correct so far?

Comment: @ChrisG yeh that's correct. currently each page is wrapped in an analytics hook (I dont like doing this). I want to essentially create a function that gets called in the compDiMount/useEffect/onload point to trigger this. (so yeh the answer below is wrong as it will call it on every mount/re-render

Comment: @ChrisG I should add, when we say "multiple pages" it is a SPA and it has different routes/views using memory router. so URL stays the same and middleware determines which view to show

Comment: @ChrisG decided on the best approach (I think). I'll fire an action in my component , then middleware will listen to this action and then fire my helper function. in the middleware I can pass state down to this function. I think that is best

Answer (score 1):

The Rules of Hooks state to only call hooks from the top level of a function.

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

You can not compose a custom hook into a `useEffect` call because that is by definition an "nested function". Instead, you should build your custom hooks to include all the hooks or `useEffect` calls they need to do *inside* the custom hook (but at the top level of the custom hook).

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

It would be helpful to have more specific code of what *exactly* you are trying to do, because currently your question is too vague to give a more direct answer.

Comment: I just want to trigger a page view onload. I have a GTM helper library so that will be called inside my hook. I don't want to directly call GTM inside myComponent as that is not scalable or reusable. so I want a hook to do this. I don't want to use HOCs as they are ugly. but maybe I don't need a hook. just a regular function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need here an `useEffect`.

```js
export const usePageView = props => {
    const counter = useSelector(state => state) // useSelector coming from react redux
    console.log(counter, '===')
}
```

```js
import { usePageView } from '../myhooks'

export const myComponent = () => {
      usePageView();
}
```

This should work.

Comment: yeh this is perfect, I think :D

Comment: This will call the function each time the component re-renders. I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `usePageView` is just a wrapper around `useSelector` and hooks must be called on every render.

Answer (score 0):

we can follow this by providing an injection function (I don't recommend it because it is outside the recommendations of the documentation):

```js
export const usePageView = props => {
    // ...
    console.log(counter, '===')
}

import { usePageView } from '../myhooks'

export const myComponent = () => {

   const hookInject = (hook, ...arg) => {
     return hook(...arg)
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      hookInject(usePageView)
   },[])

}
```

but, following the React documentation is much better to keep things we don't want from happening, just change it to:

```js
export const usePageView = props => {
    // ...
    const log = () => console.log(counter, '===')
    return { log }
}

import { usePageView } from '../myhooks'

export const myComponent = () => {
   const pageView = usePageView()

   useEffect(() => {
      pageView.log()
   },[])

}
```